# Control the name generated for the appdata folder

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have a really (hopefully) simple question.

I have developed a WPF application using VS 2012.  But when I deploy it, the appdata folder is something like this:

`/appdata/mj_q..tion_5566cef6d1c8c27c_0001.0000_da58a1f2c7427623`

How can I customize my appdata folder with a more meaningful name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to control what folder a ClickOnce application is installed in.

Comment: What other options are there for deployment?

Comment: You can either just copy the contents of the release folder, or you can use one of the installer applications out there.
I've been using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) with good results.